# How to increase amount of metrics in Google Data Studio?

Tags: excel, looker-studio

I have reached the number of 20 metrics in GDS. I am using report to do some aggregation and calculation on data and then download it to Excel file. To add more metrics I am using optional metrics but every time I refresh report I have to manually click all squares before I would be able to download this file. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Google Data Studio doesn't have a limit of 20 metrics.

Some visual component may have this limit.  If that's the case, there isn't anything that can be done.

You can try to add multiple visuals and position them close to each other, so users will think they're the same component.  Like in the picture bellow:

[image: Multiple component together]

Notice there are two tables (the first one selected), but they were positioned in a way that users will think there is only one.

Comment: Thanks for anwser but the case is that this table do some calculation and I would like to download it to csv file after all. I cannot add more than 20 metrics and it's not because of visual component. If I create second table and merge it like you do on photo I will have to download it in two pieces - not one. On Google I have found this information: 

"On a table, there's a maximum of 20 Metrics plus another 10 slots for Optional Metrics. Technically you could have only one table on the dashboard with 30 Metrics altogether to analyse with.Jul 30, 2020"

Comment: You found this in table documentation (https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044?hl=en). A table is a visual component.